# VBA to start conditional formatting (highlighting every nth row) at a row specified by another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I'm trying to highlight every nth row in an excel database. That I can do with conditional formatting with a formula =MOD(ROW(),5)=0.   The trick though is that I need that formatting to begin at a row randomly chosen by another cell with a random number generator.

Basically i have a database with a bunch of test points and I need 20 % of those to be tested every day.  It needs to be randomly selected though so that over time the entire list gets tested.

Comment: `=MOD(ROW($ZZ1)-1,5)+1=$R$1` where `$R$1` is the cell with the starting row number.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Something you should note: this isn't a free coding service. It's purpose is for coders to help other coders (even if the asker is a complete novice). That means one needs to make an attempt, show one's work, and seek help with specific issues. The solution sought here didn't require vba (see solution above). However, how you posted it amounts to simply asking "can someone write some code for free?"